# How to get calendar weeks between two days correctly

Tags: php, arrays, calendar

Hi i need a code to get the week calendar numbers between two dates. I testes a little with some code from here but always get the wrong calendar numbers.

First Code :

```
    $startDateUnix = strtotime('2014-09-21');
$endDateUnix = strtotime('2014-10-06');

$currentDateUnix = $startDateUnix;

$weekNumbers = array();
while ($currentDateUnix < $endDateUnix) {
    $weekNumbers[] = date('W', $currentDateUnix);
    $currentDateUnix = strtotime('+1 week', $currentDateUnix);
}

print_r($weekNumbers);
```

Second Code:

```
$start = '2014-09-22';
$end = '2014-10-06';
$dates = range(strtotime($start), strtotime($end),604800);
$weeks = array_map(function($v){return date('W', $v);}, $dates); // Requires PHP 5.3+
print_r($weeks);
```

and i get this out of both codes:

```
Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => 39 [2] => 40 )
```

But why is calendar week 41 not in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second code returns the result like you expect:

```
$start = '2014-09-22';
$end = '2014-10-06';
$dates = range(strtotime($start), strtotime($end),604800);
$weeks = array_map(function($v){return date('W', $v);}, $dates); // Requires PHP 5.3+
print_r($weeks);
```

output:

```
Array                                                                      
(                                                                          
    [0] => 39                                                              
    [1] => 40                                                              
    [2] => 41                                                              
)
```

the problem with your first code is that you start with 2014-09-21 (KW 38) and adding one week per loop. therefore the loop ends before the end date.

you can solve this by using the first code like this:

```
$startDateUnix = strtotime('2014-09-21');
$endDateUnix = strtotime('2014-10-06');

$currentDateUnix = $startDateUnix;

$weekNumbers = array();
while ($currentDateUnix <= $endDateUnix) {
    $weekNumbers[] = date('W', $currentDateUnix);
    $currentDateUnix = strtotime('+1 day', $currentDateUnix);
}
$weekNumbers = array_merge(array_unique($weekNumbers)); // array_merge to "reset" the keys
print_r($weekNumbers);
```

output:

```
Array                                                                      
(                                                                          
    [0] => 38                                                              
    [1] => 39                                                              
    [2] => 40                                                              
    [3] => 41                                                              
)
```

Comment: you are welcome @user3469614 - does it now work for you?